# Sean Lahman database sample queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is there any place where can I find sample queries (SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE) for Sean Lahman database? I wanna see what can be done with this database..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use to ship the database with sample queries.  Maybe I should revisit that idea.  Here are a few to get you started.

A simple one to show all of the players named "Sean:"

```
SELECT nameLast, nameFirst, debut
FROM Master
WHERE (nameFirst="Sean")
ORDER BY nameLast;
```

Here's one to show a list of players with 50 HRs in a season:

```
SELECT Master.nameLast, Master.nameFirst, Batting.HR, Batting.yearID
FROM Batting INNER JOIN Master ON Batting.playerID = Master.playerID
WHERE (((Batting.HR)>=50))
ORDER BY Batting.HR DESC;
```

Here's one to show the all-time leaders in strikeouts:

```
SELECT Master.nameLast, Master.nameFirst, Sum(Pitching.SO) AS SumOfSO
FROM Pitching INNER JOIN Master ON Pitching.playerID = Master.playerID
GROUP BY Pitching.playerID, Master.nameLast, Master.nameFirst
ORDER BY Master.nameLast;
```

There are several websites with tutorials on using the database that include sample queries. See:
http://webdev.cas.msu.edu/cas992/weeks/week5.html
http://www.hardballtimes.com/main/article/databases-for-sabermetricians-part-one/

You can find more by googling 'sql lahman'

Answer (score 3):

This database can do most anything except game-by-game analysis, for that you will need to go to Retrosheet {http://www.retrosheet.org/game.htm}.

But let's say that you want to replicate the totals you see on [Baseball-Reference.com](http://www.baseball-reference.com/), you could easily do that.

If you want some advanced metrics (Sabermetric-like stats), I recommend Tom Tango's website. There you can find help to do your [own queries](http://www.insidethebook.com/ee/index.php/site/comments/woba_year_by_year_calculations/) for wOBA. You can also formulate (try to duplicate) FanGraph's or Baseball-Reference's WAR.

Basically, anything you want (provided you can do the calculations/master the SQL syntax) from this *except* game-by-game or pitch-by-pitch types of data.

Here's a query to determine Salary by games played (offensively and defensively) to figure out how much a player cost/makes per game. (T-SQL w/ SQL Server 2012 Express)

```
select
    m.namefirst,
    m.namelast,
    s.yearID,
    s.teamID,
    s.salary,
    Cast ('162' as Int) as FullSeason,
    round(sum(s.salary)*1.00/162,0) as Game_Rate,
    sum (case when s.playerID=b.playerID then f.g else 0 end) as Gm_App_Field,
    b.g as Batting,
    --sum(case when s.playerID=b.playerID and s.yearID=b.yearID then b.g else 0 end) as Gm_App_Hit,
    sum (case when s.playerID=b.playerID then f.innouts else 0 end) as InnOuts,
    sum(F.InnOuts)/27 as FullGames,
    round((sum (case when s.playerID=b.playerID then f.g else 0 end)/162.0)*s.salary,0) as PayByGmFielding,
    round(sum(b.g*s.salary)/162,0) as PayByGmHitting,
    round((sum(F.InnOuts)/27)*(s.salary/162),0) as PlayingSalary
from Fielding f
     inner join batting b
     on f.playerID=b.playerID and f.yearID=b.yearID
     inner join salaries s
     on f.playerID=s.playerID and f.yearID=s.yearID
     inner join [master] m
     on b.playerID=m.playerID and f.playerID=m.playerID and s.playerID=m.playerID
where
     f.yearID = '2013' and f.POS <> 'P' --b.playerID = 'zimmejo02'   
group by 
    m.namefirst,m.namelast, s.yearID , s.teamID, s.salary, b.g
```

Which outputs this:

```
namefirst   namelast    yearID  teamID  salary  FullSeason  Game_Rate   Gm_App_Field    Batting InnOuts FullGames   PayByGmFielding PayByGmHitting  PlayingSalary
A.J.    Pollock         2013    ARI    491000   162         9093         119       137     2897    107     360672      1245685     324302
```

You can also create your own searches, here's one with players who have more BB/SO with full player cards, including the WAR I came up with (may be off a little from FanGraphs or Baseball Reference) - (T-SQL w/ SQL Server 2012 Express)

```
--1. Retrives Full Player Records of guys with more BB than SO
select 
    m.namefirst,
    m.namelast,
    b.yearID,
    b.yearID-m.birthyear as Age,
    b.G,b.AB,b.R,b.H,b.[2B],b.[3B],b.HR,b.RBI,b.SB,b.BB,b.SO, left(round((b.bb*1.000/b.SO),3),4) [BB/SO Rate], left(round((b.h*1.000/b.ab),3),5) as Average
    ,b.IBB,b.HBP,b.SH,b.SF,b.SF,b.GIDP,case when br.yearID=b.yearID and br.playerID=b.playerID then br.War else 'error' end as WAR
from [master] m 
    inner join batting b on b.playerID=m.playerID
    inner join BR_WAR_2013 br on br.playerID=m.playerID
where b.SO <> 0 and b.AB > 300 and b.bb>b.SO
group by 
    m.namefirst,
    m.namelast,
    b.yearID,
    b.yearID-m.birthyear,
    b.G,b.AB,b.R,b.H,b.[2B],b.[3B],b.HR,b.RBI,b.SB,b.BB,b.SO, left(round((b.bb*1.000/b.SO),3),4), left(round((b.h*1.000/b.ab),3),5)
    ,b.IBB,b.HBP,b.SH,b.SF,b.SF,b.GIDP,case when br.yearID=b.yearID and br.playerID=b.playerID then br.War else 'error' end
having case when br.yearID=b.yearID and br.playerID=b.playerID then br.War else 'error' end <> 'error'
order by b.yearID desc, left(round((b.bb*1.000/b.SO),3),4)  desc
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Paul,  I am wondering if you could help you formulate my own WAR calculation? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I've missed this. If you want to calculate WAR in R, this may be a good option. I have not tested it. https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-add-war-metrics-to-your-lahman-database/

Comment: There's a couple ways to compute WAR. Bbref (sometimes called "rWAR") does it one one and Fangraphs ("fWAR") does it another way. If you want to explore the origins and thoughts behind the calculations you can go here to decide which way you'd like to go. http://www.insidethebook.com/ee/index.php/category/Linear_Weights/

I will check my SQL queries to see if I still have my SQL implementation (instead of R or Python) of WAR. I'm pretty sure at the time I used Bbref's version. http://www.insidethebook.com/ee/index.php/site/article/fangraphs_ra9_wins_v_brcom_rwar/

Comment: A shortcut on the linear weights table you'd need to create is here called the "Guts" table. http://www.fangraphs.com/guts.aspx?type=cn With an explanation here: http://www.fangraphs.com/library/the-beginners-guide-to-deriving-woba/

Comment: Hey, @Paul . Thanks. I'll have to check those links out.  Thinking back on this, WAR always seems like a magic number because of the GUTS linear weights formulas are seemingly arbitrary (they're not) but there is no formula published to test/rebuild the weights.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for... 
https://www.beyondtheboxscore.com/2011/1/4/1912914/custom-woba-and-linear-weights-through-2010-baseball-databank-data

http://basql.wikidot.com/woba